# The right way to show a image in Qt

Tags: c++, image, qt, label

I am new to Qt and almost every tutorial I find says to add the image to a QLabel using setPixmap(). Maybe this is the right way, but it doesn't feels to be, since using a label for a image seems to go beyond the purpose of a label.

Could anyone tell me if there is a "right way" or a special Class for this, or if the "Label way" is the right one, not just the simple one.

Comment: "since using a label for a image seems to go beyond the purpose of a label." -> Eh? It is the right way for simple cases like this. I do not think you checked out the documentation and examples for this. It is one of the main purposes, i.e. use cases, for `QLabel`.

Comment: @LaszloPapp When I asked this question I didn't knew it...but after it got answered 3 months a go by Wagmare it was claer enough. Please see the comments under the chosen answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

easiest way is to use a QLabel.in ImageViewer example
 http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-imageviewer.html they use QLabel ..

another way

```
QGraphicsView view(&scene);
    QGraphicsPixmapItem item(QPixmap("c:\\test.png"));
    scene.addItem(&item);
```

Comment: Agreed. `QGraphicsView` has a lot of powerful features that won't be needed or used if you just need to display an image. `QLabel` would be the more appropriate because, although it's name might suggest that it's primary purpose is to be textual, it's actual purpose is to be a light-weight `QWidget` used for read-only purposes. i.e. it is used to show the user information with almost no code to handle user events, like clicks.

Comment: I maybe will need to grab clicks and position of the click in the image to select it as a boundary for OpenCV. I guess this wont be possible with QLabel, what would you recommend instead?

Comment: u can override mousePressEvent in QLable and with event->pos() u can get the position of click . better u can go for graphicsview and graphicspixmap item .. u can have screenPos(), scenePos(), pos() and detect ur mouse click position in overriding mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)

Comment: or install an event filter

Comment: What about "with almost no code to handle user events, like clicks"?

Comment: I chose to mark this as the answer because it shows actual documentation from Qt that the proper way of showing images is in a QLabel, as weird as it might sound.

Comment: "The QGraphicsView approach seems slight overkill for a simple image.." -> I am also with @FrankOsterfeld there. Unfortunately, lazy readers might pick up the QGV code from this answer without reading the documentation further on, which is probably wrong in general.

Answer (score 5):

Using QLabel is the usual way to display an image in a QtWidgets-based UI. That might indeed feel a bit awkward, as QLabel's API is mostly concerned with text rendering. However, it does the job and there's no other class dedicated to only painting images. One could think of writing his own class (taking a QPixmap, reimplementing paintEvent(), sizeHint()), but that would only make sense to me if functionality is needed that QLabel lacks.

There are of course many other ways to paint an image, depending on the context, like images on buttons (QToolButton, QPushButton, ...), images in graphics scenes (QGraphicsScene/View) etc., but they all serve either more specialized or more complex use cases.

Comment: Just to be clear, what mean of "canonical" are you using? (English is not my mother language, so I rather to be sure about what you said than to assume)

Comment: "usual", "straight-forward", "default"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple class that isn't Label based. I suppose it depends on what you personally feel is the proper way to do it and what you need to do with it. I prefer implementing my own class so you can add on to it later(maybe you want to manipulate the image).

**imagewidget.h**

```
#ifndef IMAGEWIDGET_H
#define IMAGEWIDGET_H

#include <QPainter>
#include <QImage>
#include <QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QPainter;
class QImage;
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class ImageWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ImageWidget(const QString &filename, QWidget* parent = 0);
    ~ImageWidget();

    bool load(const QString &fileName);
    bool save(const QString &fileName);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);

private:
    QImage img;
};

#endif
```

**imagewidget.cpp**

```
#include <QDebug>
#include "imagewidget.h"

ImageWidget::ImageWidget(const QString &filename, QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    img.load(filename);

    setMinimumWidth(img.width());
    setMinimumHeight(img.height());
    setMaximumWidth(img.width());
    setMaximumHeight(img.height());

    this->show();
}

bool ImageWidget::load(const QString &fileName)
{
    img.load(fileName);
    return true;
}

bool ImageWidget::save(const QString &fileName)
{
    img.save(fileName, "PNG");
    return true;
}

ImageWidget::~ImageWidget()
{
}

void ImageWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setViewport(0, 0, width(), height());
    painter.setWindow(0, 0, width(), height());
    painter.drawImage(0, 0, img);
}
```